# How is the post-credits scene for the original series connected to Rebellion?

Tags: madoka-magica

In the post-credits scene of the series

> Homura is seen wandering the desert where the scene concludes with her sprouting dark wings and flying off.

After seeing Rebellion, this seems connected in that

> it takes place in Homura's rewritten universe after she becomes a demon, which is what the wings represent.

I'm not too sure though, what confuses me is that Homura is

> still wearing Madoka's ribbon in the post-credits scene, while in Rebellion she gave it back in the end after her "we may end up enemies" speech.

Ultimately, what does this scene represent now that Rebellion exists?

Comment: keep in mind there is a movie adaptation of the original series which Rebellion was made to follow, it's quite possible the series was made without Rebellion in mind and that the movie adaptation corrects continuity issues when Rebellion was being developed

Comment: That's a good thing to point out and keep in mind for these things. However, the plot of the series and the two movies is identical. The only new thing brought to the table by the movies is new animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, this scene is supposed to show

> that Homura has begun transforming into a witch at the end of the series. This explains why the wings look like something out of a witch labyrinth. It would also explains her ribbon: it still takes place in the universe with adjusted laws that Madoka created. Additionally, it would explain why she was able to hear Madoka - it was because Madoka would be coming to claim her soon.

If you go by this, then it can be assumed

> that the Incubators trapped Homura in their barrier pretty much immediately after this scene, and then the plot of Rebellion takes place.

So the wings would actually be

> witch wings, not demon wings. However,  there seem to be some similarities between the powers of a witch and Demon-Homura. For example, in her redone universe, she is shown to have bird familiars that look suspiciously like witch familiars. We could also see that Homura also had her soul gem transformed into something - not a grief seed though, because it wasn't despair that transformed her, but love - or so Homura says.

So it would make sense that

> her witch wings look similar to her demon wings at the end of the Rebellion movie.